# Vapor 3.1.10 Xcode-11.3.1 Compile issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, vapor

I have created a new vapor project using terminal. When I try building the project I get an error "Redefination of Module" for multiple modules. I tried cleaning the build did everything possible but unable to figure out the error. If anyone had the same issue and was able to fix it, please let me know. below is the attached screen shot[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with Homebrew and Xcode's command line tools. Run `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`, clean and then build again

Comment: 0xTim - you are just amazing. It worked like charm.

Comment: Just as a follow up, this has now been fixed in Homebrew so if you update Homebrew to 2.2.13 this issue should no longer appear